# Is AWS SES Asynchronous?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

I'm using PHP with AWS' SDK. I have a question regarding SES service. If I push an email to be sent to SES in the same process as other parts of a script being ran. For example, sending an email directly via SES within the same process that handles user registration, will the PHP process lockup until SES completes the sending of the email? Or does SES go into an internal queue of sort and send from there as it sees fit?

Or, is it smarter to push the email data up to an SQS queue to handle the sending via SES?

Comment: in short no it wont lock until sent, it will only lock until request to send is complicated (ms)

Comment: So when ->Send(), is called on the client object, it locks?

Answer (score 1):

Your call to SES returns once SES has accepted your message.

It does not block until SES has delivered the message.

SES tries to deliver the message quickly, but will actually retry for up to 12 hours, according to "Scenario 2" here: http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/Tx1S0ND7F4PCCGN/

Optionally, delivery, failure, and bounce notifications are returned asynchronously (later) via Simple Notification Service. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications.html

Comment: Ok, so there's no need to push the process of SES ->send to be ran within a seperate queue outside of the current process?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have a command or another function that gets called from the background and then send the email, so to not make the user wait during the process. You would setup listeners, that listen for the register event and then fire the event on registration process, then process the tasks. The listeners would then process the event. Where you could send the email, or send to SQS, so your worker machines can send the email out.

Here is a good video about how to do this, in this day and age, not like how people did it 5 years ago. https://laracasts.com/series/commands-and-domain-events

If you are sending the email from the same request object, the user will have to wait for the email to send, if you just send the user data to the queue, and setup a command that processes all messages from the queue and sends fires appropriate command with the message data, then you can send email that way too. But really I think that would be over kill for simple email sending. Just send it from the background process on the machine that received the request. If you have an architecture that separates web machines from background workers, you could just send the data to the queue from the web server on register and then the workers would send the email once they receive the item from the queue.